# Disable concurrency checking on property in Lightswitch

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-lightswitch

Lightswitch is checking concurrency in SaveChanges on each property of each entity. Is it possible to disable this checking for some property of some entity?

For example:
Entity A:

- Property A (check concurrency)
- Property B (do not check concurrency)

Thank you for response.

Comment: LS stores Entity frameworks's files (*.csdl, *.msl and *.ssdl) in ServerGenerated/GeneratedArtifacts. Conceptual model (*.csdl) contains conceptual model of each entity within its properties. Entity Framework define ConcurrencyMode attribute. LS set this attribute to "Fixed". If I set it to "None", concurrency is not checked. Problem is that LS updates these files to default during data store's updates, building and so on.

Comment: I think, concurrency checking can be disabled in Lightswitch using custom RIA service witch use EF model with concurrency mode set to None.